# QT: QGraphicsView not updating from inside loop

Tags: qt

I'm trying to draw a picture to the screen repeatedly from inside an infinite loop. When I try to draw the picture to the QGraphicsView, it doesn't update unless I break from the loop. Here is my function with the infinite loop:

```
void MainWindow::displayNoise() {
    QImage noise(WIDTH, HEIGHT, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    float t = 0;

    while (true) {
        // Populate noise

        rendered_image = noise;
        DisplayQImage(rendered_image);
        t += 0.200;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}
```

And here is `DisplayQImage()`:

```
void MainWindow::DisplayQImage(QImage &i)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(i));
    graphics_scene.addPixmap(pixmap);
    graphics_scene.setSceneRect(pixmap.rect());
    ui->scene_display->setScene(&graphics_scene);
}
```

Note that `graphics_scene` and `rendered_image` are members of `MainWindow`. If I insert a break statement after my call to `DisplayQImage` then the first frame renders, but if I don't exit the `displayNoise` function then the widget doesn't update. I set up a signal so that when I press `N` it calls `displayNoise`, and I know the loop is looping. Why isn't the picture showing?

Comment: It is a bad idea to run such a loop inside a GUI thread. You cannot affect widgets from non-main threads, but long synchronous operations should not be performed there. But for some cases where an immediate update is required, [repaint()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint) can be used

Comment: See also the example about [parallel processing QImage via QtConcurrent API](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentmap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not giving the eventloop time to do it's thing. Your function is being called from the eventloop, and the rendering is called from the same eventloop, because they live in the same thread. So you have two options:

- write your code in an asyncronous way, eg. with a QTimer.
- manually call the eventloop: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html#processEvents

I think the first option is probably the nicest way.